# new_CppObject_xp incorrectly reports an error when passing an Rcpp object to another

Tags: r, rcpp

I've got two Rcpp-wrapped classes, `A` and `B`. `A`'s constructor extracts some information from its parameter, and prints it out to prove it worked.

`B` takes an object of `A` as a constructor parameter — and reports an error as if extraction in `A`'s constructor failed. But as `A` did print out the extracted data, it couldn't fail.

How do I get `B` to accept `A` as a parameter without erroring out?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
#include <Rcpp.h>

struct A {
  Rcpp::NumericVector y;

  A(Rcpp::List x)
    : y(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(x["foo"]))
  {
    Rcpp::Rcout << y;
  }
};

struct B {
  B(A x) { }
};

RCPP_MODULE(A) {
  Rcpp::class_<A>("A")
  .constructor<Rcpp::List>();
}

RCPP_MODULE(B) {
  Rcpp::class_<B>("B")
  .constructor<A>();
}
')

Aobj <- new(A, list(foo=1:3))
Bobj <- new(B, Aobj)
```

Output:

```
> source('testcase.R', echo=TRUE)

> library(Rcpp)

> Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
+ #include <Rcpp.h>
+ 
+ struct A {
+   Rcpp::NumericVector y;
+ 
+   A(Rcpp::List x)
+     : y(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector> .... [TRUNCATED] 

> Aobj <- new(A, list(foo=1:3))
1 2 3
> Bobj <- new(B, Aobj)
Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index='foo'].
>
```

Comment: @duckmayr, in my original code, before making MWE, `y` was a private member, not meant to be exposed anywhere. This looked like an irrelevant detail to MWE, and if I have to, I can make it public… but as you state, something's still weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to explain why [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52684800/8416610) works. With `RCPP_MODULE(A)` you are exposing the C++ struct `A` as a reference class in R. That is done automatically. However, when you call `Bobj <- new(B, Aobj)`, there is no information how to convert from this reference class to the required C++ struct. By using `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(A)` you are creating specialization of `Rcpp::wrap` and `Rcpp::as` to convert between C++ and R objects in both ways. Since we are only missing the R to C++ conversion, i.e. `Rcpp::as`, the following is also enough:

```cpp
#include <RcppCommon.h>
struct A;
RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(A)

#include <Rcpp.h>

struct A {
  Rcpp::NumericVector y;

  A(Rcpp::List x)
    : y(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(x["foo"]))
  {
    Rcpp::Rcout << y;
  }
};

struct B {
  B(A x) { }
};

RCPP_MODULE(A) {
  Rcpp::class_<A>("A")
  .constructor<Rcpp::List>();
}

RCPP_MODULE(B) {
  Rcpp::class_<B>("B")
  .constructor<A>();
}

/*** R
Aobj <- new(A, list(foo=1:3))
Bobj <- new(B, Aobj)
*/
```

Comment: One more question: why did my MWE work after removing the `: y(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(x["foo"]))` line?

Comment: @liori Interesting question. Note that the error is also triggered by calling `new(A, Aobj)`. Since there is no known way to convert `Aobj` to the corresponding struct, it is treated as an `SEXP` which is passed to `A`‘s constructor.

Comment: Ah, so it's just a matter of the copy constructor getting involved. Pretty clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When things are not working, it's good to (re-)read some documentation. Specifically, [Rcpp Extending (PDF)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf), section 3.2.

I added the following at the beginning of the C++ code:

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>
struct A;
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(A);
```

…and it works fine now. I admit I don't fully understand what happens here yet, but this solution is solving both the MWE and my original code problems.